# Cropping Black Bars on a Video

Tags: interface, video-sequence-editor, edit-mode, transforms

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3K7ESn-AVW0

I want to use this green screen video in my blender video editor movie, but it has black bars on it. I've tried cropping and resizing it, but when I render it the quality goes down. Also, does editing it directly from the video properties or editing it from the transform strip make any difference?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The footage of the tigert has unwanted black bars above and below it.
Cropping it stretches and distorts the picture.
But using image overlay leaves blank empty space.

[image: The scale isn't the problem.]

[image: As you can see, when you crop it, it becomes granulated.]

I changed the scale and the black bars were still there. The original footage has black bars. But removing them by cropping makes the picture look granulated.

If the problem is the number of pixels, how do I find out what the number of pixels are, and how do I change it?

Comment: You can add an image instead of a link to watch a video. The video also does not show the problem you describe.

Comment: It looks like the image you imported does not match the size for the project in blender. Make sure that they are the same number of pixels. Also check if the source you are using is using square pixels... that might be the reason why the image looks squeezed.